# Vertical menu: check if subpage is selected to open menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I have a vertical menu that contains submenu items.
If the submenu page is currently being viewed I would like to open the menu to show the user on which page he is.

I think I need to do this in the js but don't know how since my js is crap....

This is a WordPress menu so here is the menu-output:

```
<div id="menu">
<div class="menu-webshop-menu-container">
    <ul id="menu-webshop-menu" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-210" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent menu-item-has-children menu-item-210">
            <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu selected">
                <li id="menu-item-203" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat current-menu-item menu-item-203" style="">
                    <a href="http://www.domain.com/woocommerce/product-categorie/clothing/">Clothing</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This js created the open and close for the submenu:

```
<div id="menu">
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'webshop-menu') ); ?>
</div>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#menu > div > ul > li > a").click(function (e) { // binding onclick
        if ($(this).next(".sub-menu").hasClass('selected')) {
            $("#menu .selected ul").slideUp(100); // hiding popups
            $("#menu .selected").removeClass("selected");
        } else {
            $("#menu .selected ul").slideUp(100); // hiding popups
            $("#menu .selected").removeClass("selected");
            if ($(this).next(".sub-menu").length) {
                $(this).next(".sub-menu").addClass("selected"); // display popup
                $(this).next(".sub-menu").children().slideDown(200);
            }
       }
       e.stopPropagation();
   }); 
});
</script>
```

I don't think I can do this with css because the js adds a class to the submenu when it is clicked. So the class doesn't exist before the click.

M.

Comment: What do you mean by "So the class doesn't exist before the click". Of course it shouldn't be there because that's not the purpose of that class. Your question is  a bit unclear.

Comment: Well the class exists in my css file but as the js states it get's added when the link for the submenu is clicked `selected`